# Disable all code formatting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, formatting

I would like to disable all code formatting an performed actions on save in Eclipse 3.6 (Windows 7).

I turned off Save actions --> Perform the selected actions on save (I thougth this would be enough, but no) and Code Style --> Clean Up --> Active Profile (Eclipse built in) --> Format source code and Remove trailing whitespaces.
But when I save the file whitespaces are still removed.

There aren't project specific settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are using any plugins such as AnyEdit tools which enable this by default.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem.
I think when I installed Extended vs. Presentation I installed AnyEdit too.